Pixelated Images in Geoserver SLD-Style
I use external png graphics for a fill-style in geoserver. I directly upload them via the upload image dialogue in the SLD-editor. In the preview of the SLD-editor the icons look quite crips. However, in OpenLayers or Leaflet - where I use the geoserver layer - the icons are pixelated and I can not find a solution for this.
The SLD code:

 <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
<sld:Fill>
  <sld:GraphicFill>
    <sld:Graphic>
     <ExternalGraphic xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
       <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="4.png" />
       <Format>image/png</Format>
      </ExternalGraphic>

      <sld:Size>50</sld:Size>
    </sld:Graphic>
  </sld:GraphicFill>
</sld:Fill>
<sld:VendorOption name="graphic-margin">10</sld:VendorOption>   </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>


Here is it what it looks like inthe SLD-editor:

And here in leaflet:


are you comparing like for like in image formats?

Are you asking if the two screenshots show the same thing? If that's the case, then yes. The screenshots show the same polygon both times.

but is one of them a png and the other a Jpeg? do they have the same anti-aliasing settings etc - please add the actual request URL parameters

I don't know the parameter settings of the editor preview, but I used the OpenLayers preview in geoserver to check if the problem is setting related. It seem's like the problem is not leaflet exclusive. No matter if I set it to png or jpeg(looks even worth), disable/enable anti aliasing, it looks bad.

please add the actual request URL parameters -  you can see then by opening the image in a new browser tab

do you mean the wms url for the geoserver preview? that goes like:
//geoserverurl/workspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=cp&bbox=491817.71875%2C5744469.5%2C863579.5625%2C5910750.499999999&width=768&height=34 3&srs=EPSG%3A25832&styles=&format= application/openlayers#toggle

I meant the actual URL for the image tile in both cases. Open the network tab in your browser debugger and look for images

Ian, excuse the late reply and thanks a lot. I managed to get it working wit svgs and it looks perfect. Forgot about the PNG approach. I recommend using SVGs over PNG as größere handles them pretty well.
